# How to write a Visual Studio macro to reassemble partial C# class files into a single one?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Any example to show me how to start like getting the list of c# partial class files with visual studio sdk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the CodeClass to the EnvDTE80.CodeClass2 interface. The Parts property should give you all the partials in the project.